# Server error when running on prompt command

Tags: server, local

Why the server doesn't respond on localhost 3000?

I have this in Sublime Text 3

```
var http = require("http");

var = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  response.end ("<html><body>Link on Box</body></html");

});
server.listen(3000);
```

I try to runn in Prompt Command and I have this error:

[image: Prompt command]

Comment: post all errors and the information here to reproduce the problem and help you

Comment: I'm using node.js

Comment: ReferenceError: res is not defined
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\curso_node\noticias.js:5:2)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:602:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:117:23)